# Azure WebRole VIP Swap shows runtime error

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

ASP.NET Web application is hosted in WIndows Azure.

I noticed that when I perform a VIP SWAP, the yellow screen of death gets displayed for few seconds. Has anyone noticed this and what's the possible fix for it. Is there a way to show offline page while VIP is happening?

[image: VIP SWAP]

Comment: how many instances do you have?

Comment: Did you alter your service configuration?

Comment: I read that when you made a change in your service configuration (i.e number os instances) this could happen...my suggestion: open a ticket with microsoft support. Cheers